# What am I doing wrong? 405 error when trying to save values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to factories and all I'm trying to do is save the current settings from page load to the db.  Then I want to update it when I click somewhere.  However, I can't get it to save to db because of error `POST http://localhost:8080/api/settings/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

EDIT - Issue was not with code but I had not actually put the POST in my server... sorry about stupid

Comment: This problem has less to do with your Angular code and more to do with your server. Your server is responding with the `405` status. If you need help with understanding why the server is responding that way you should specify what your server is (and then provide relevant configs/code from your server).

Comment: oh my god... i am sorry i am so stupid.  i did not have a api.post method :(  sorry for the stupid question shall I delete?

Answer (score 0):

Error seems pretty clear, `(Method Not Allowed)` means that particular API will not accept POSTs, which is what you are sending on `Settings.create()`.
You may need to create a POST method on your API or change the method that `vm.create` calls.

Comment: i am idiot i did not do that.  i have done the needful and it is working now.  thank you